# Runtime Conversion of Array of Bytes from .ICO to .PNG (Portable C# code)

Tags: c#, image-processing, unity-game-engine, runtime, file-conversion

Title says it all! I would want to convert an array of bytes/file from **.ICO** to **.PNG**. (preferably array of bytes)

After lots of research I found only one good answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10377361

Though it's Windows-specific and I want to port my project to Windows and Mac at least.
Some on UnityAnswers suggested writing my own ICO loader [wikipedia_article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29#Icon_resource_structure) but I would truly appreciate some other solution that does not leave me to this only option of writing my own loader which requires more time to perform. I hope somebody would have some portable c# solution for this issue.

Here's my question from [UnityAnswers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1008131/cant-download-ico-wwwtexture-only-accepts-png-and.html):

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anybody can provide some guiding/directions?

Comment: Just to get some background, where are you getting the .ico from?

Comment: I am executing my JaveScript method from C# via third-party C++ engine and getting a callback with a string result representing the download link of a .ICO file. And in turn this image file represents the FAVICON (site icon) of the current opened website in my application.


Example of the string: [Google's FAVICON link](https://www.google.com/favicon.ico)